# What options do I have when extracting business logic from a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logic, software-design

I want to extract the business logic from the logistic system coded in the backend of a Rails app, as it is becoming more and more complex. I'm pretty sure there are better options than hard-coding lots of ifs, even if embellished through nice OOP.

I would like to know what options do I have for such purpose. A little bit of research led me to Treetop or Rools parser libraries. Are these good options for what I'm looking to do? Is there a pattern/concept that I'm missing here and I can learn coding it myself instead?

I'd love to hear your opinions and recommendations.

Thanks a lot

ps: Oh, and is it really a win to use a new language for business logic instead of just hard-coding it? Because what I can see from the examples in Treetop, is like a DSL on top of Ruby.

Comment: It's not a "new" language at all. That is a core concept of using ruby, that you can create a DSL to manage the semantics and syntactic sugar (kinda) around a problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: ok, that's a good point. But like any DSL you (and future maintainers) must learn it. I'm just wondering if it adds too much "conceptual" overhead

Comment: That is very true. But the goal of most ruby dsl's i've used like the one for rspec is to make it really easy to understand. Almost like writing the instructions in plain english in that case. If it's cryptic then why would it be beneficial to use in any case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to extract the business logic into a gem. Most of it would be just copy/paste with some tweaks here and there.

The big benefit of this approach is that your gem would just focus on your business logic, so it would not deal with representation etc. As long as you test everything with tdd you should be fine.

Best case would be to just require your gem and then call its most important method like:

```
require 'mygem'
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def important_method arg1, arg2
    MyGem.compute_results arg1, arg2
  end
end
```

This way your code stays clean and modular, furthermore you could easily use your logic in a different rails app.

This assumes your logic is some hardcore calculations / ruby code. If your business logic are some sql statements leave them in your app.

Comment: In this case, it mixes sql and calculations. I think extracting to a gem is not the best options. I really appreciate your answer! Thanks

Comment: You can either try to extract only the calculations or instead of creating a gem create a plugin. Plugins are not as modular as gems but you can usually port them to other applications with minor effort.

Comment: But why would you want to export the logic? At least how I see it is one of the most specific parts of the program, so I'm not going to use that exact logic again. What I could use again is the language to define the rules, so it makes sense to make a gem with this. Why do you want to export those rules if you know that you are not going to use them again in any other place?